# Bedeutung von "das besondere Etwas"

Tags: meaning

> ...eine Persönlichkeit mit dem richtigen Gespür für unsere Kunden und dem Verständnis für **das besondere Etwas**...

Es geht um ein Angebot für eine Servicekraft und eine Hotelfachfrau/einen Hotelfachmann, die Kunden mit viel Geld individuelle Angebote machen sollen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Das sollte wohl eigentlich „das gewisse Etwas“ heißen und das ist laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Etwas):

> eine schwer definierbare, anziehend wirkende Art, Eigenschaft, Fähigkeit: sie hat das gewisse Etwas

Gemeint ist damit vermutlich etwas wie, dass der Bewerber sein Gespür für Kunden auch umzusetzen weiß.

Auf mich wirkt es ehrlich gesagt nur wie eine hohle Phrase, um das Angebot irgendwie außergewöhnlicher erscheinen zu lassen.

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass es um Verständnis für Sexappeal geht.

Comment: Ich glaube, das ist falsch. Die Person soll ja nicht selbst "das besondere Etwas haben", sondern Gespür dafür. Im Zusammenhang mit reicher Kundschaft ist auch davon auszugehen, dass diese eben etwas besonderes haben wollen. Daher denke ich, dass die Antwort etwas am Thema vorbei geht.

Answer (score 3):

Das gesuchte Personal sollte auf folgende Frage eine Antwort haben:

> Was muss ich dem reichen Kunden anbieten, damit er darauf eingeht?

Übersättigte Wohlstandsbürger sind schwer zu beglücken, weil sie schon alles kennen. Zum Erfolg kommen nur Leute, die sich in den reichen Gast hineinversetzen können und ahnen, was ihn lockt und überrascht. Ein einfacher Weckdienst oder mehrlagiges Klopapier kann das nicht sein, da muss schon das Aparte her – das besondere Etwas.

Comment: Ich glaube zwar, dass es mehr um das Wie als um das Was geht, aber die Antwort ist um Längen besser, als die andere. :)